# Removing the first element in an array and returning it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public T removeItem(){
    T t;

    if(array == null)
        t = null;

    t = array[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
         array[i] = array[i + 1];

   return t;

}
```

Here's my code for a method that is suppose to remove the oldest element of an array while returning it until all elements are removed, which would cause the method to use the if statement and end the removal + retrieval loop. However, it would loop nonstop at just the 1st element.

For example.

What I want to happen with an array that has [1, 2, 3].

```
1 is returned.

2 is returned. 

3 is returned.
```

and then it ends because all elements have been returned and removed.

Instead, I get a repeat of:

```
1 is returned.
```

over and over and over and over and over.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class DsArray<T> implements ArrQ<T>
{


private final T[] array ;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private int numberOfItems;
private boolean initialized = false;
private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 10000;

public DsArray() {
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
} 

public DsArray(int desiredCapacity) {
    if (desiredCapacity <= MAX_CAPACITY) {


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] tempArray = (T[]) new Object[desiredCapacity]; 
        array = tempArray;
        numberOfItems = 0;
        initialized = true;
    }
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Attempt to create a array " +
                                        "whose capacity exceeds " +
                                        "allowed maximum.");
} 



public boolean addItem(T item){

    boolean result = true;
    if (full()) {
        result = false;
    } else { 
        array[numberOfItems] = item;
        numberOfItems++;
    } 
    return result;
}


public T removeItem(){

    int n = array.length;
    T t = array[0];
    if(empty())
        return null;
    for(int i = 0; i < n -1; i++)
        array[i] = array[i + 1];

    return t;

}
public boolean full(){

    return numberOfItems >= array.length;

}

public boolean empty(){

    return numberOfItems == 0;
}

}
```

Code for the class added.

```
public class Tester
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{

    ArrQ<Integer> theQ = new DsArray<Integer>(5);

    // Testing addItem
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Integer new = new Integer(2 * i);
        if (!(theQ.full()))
        {
            theQ.addItem(new);
            System.out.println(new + " is added");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It is full");
        }
    }

    // Testing removeItem
    while (!(theQ.empty()))
    {
        Integer old = theQ.removeItem();
        System.out.println(old + " is returned.");
    }
    Integer noItem = theQ.removeItem();
    if (noItem == null)
        System.out.println(" ");
}
```

code for main class added.

The addItem() method works for me. The removeItem() method doesn't.

Solved. Forgot numberOfItems--; after the for statement.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: where is array[] defined, at functional level  or at class level.kindly post the complete code.

Comment: Check the condition for for loop: `i = array.length - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you missed to maintain counter on removal as in

```
public T removeItem(){

    int n = array.length;
    T t = array[0];
    if(empty())
        return null;
    for(int i = 0; i < n -1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    numberOfItems--; // Missed piece
    return t;

}
```

Also, the description is inaccurate, your code(as is) repeatedly returns the last element and not the first one.

Comment: Yeah. I just checked. I thought it was the first since it just nonstop looping so it skipped my mind to check the earlier outputs.

Answer (score 1):

From the code shared above, one thing that you've missed out is :

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) // notice the condition to iterate
```

Comment: My bad. That was just a typo. Its in my actual code.

Comment: @FiftySentos Please update the question in that case with an MCVE as stated by shmosel as well in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out ;)

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int n=a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        a[i]=a[i+1];
    }n--;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
}
```

Output:
2
3
4
5

Comment: It works by itself as a program but I need to return the a[i] in a method. I know how to increment the elements to remove the 1st element but not sure on how to actually return the 1st element as the result for the method.

Comment: @FiftySentos it will be great help if you post the MCVE and also state the exact requirement in question clearly